# Where is it safe to call rb_backtrace in live app

Tags: ruby, gdb, backtrace

When I'm debugging a live application and want to get the current ruby stacktrace, the good way to get that information is to call `rb_backtrace()` from the attached `gdb`. But is it always safe? Are there any specific application states where I should avoid calling that function?

If it's relevant, the application is being run by a unicorn worker.

Comment: I'm not sure it's ever unsafe, but if you're debugging a mission critical process I'd be extra super careful.

Answer (score -1):

In the prod environment, it's not a good practice to use `rb_backtrace()`.

you can try this. very easy to use in ROR apps, i think.

https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake

Comment: Airbrake is cool for handling exceptions and other events, but that's not what I'm after. I just need to sample the ruby stacktrace from a live application at random point in time and restore the process.